# What are the polynomials $p \in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $\vert p(z) \vert \le 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb U$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

The question is *What are the polynomials $p \in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $\vert p(z) \vert \le 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb U$?* $\mathbb U$ stands for the complex numbers of modulus $1$.

Hint:

> Think to Fourier series

I wrote a solution below using the hint. However, any solution using a different approach is more than welcomed!

Comment: What is $\Bbb U$?

Comment: What is $\;\Bbb U\;$ ?

Comment: Complex numbers with modulus equal to $1$. Question updated.

Comment: Downvoter, a comment would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is not a puzzle website. If you have a solution, then you should post it. If you are looking for other solutions, you should show your solution and state that you want different solutions.

Comment: @BartMichels Will do!

Comment: It would be nice to have a puzzle-section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\mathcal P = \{p \in \mathbb Z[x] \mid \vert p(x) \vert \le 1 \text{ for all } z \in \mathbb U\}$. As for
$$p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k$$ we have
$$a_k = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} P(e^{it}) e^{-kt}\ dt$$ we can conclude that the coefficients of $P$ belong to $\{0, -1, 1\}$. Moreover for $p, q \in \mathcal P$, $pq \in \mathcal P$. Therefore if $p \in \mathcal P$, $p^2 \in \mathcal P$ from which we deduce that only one coefficient of $p$ can be non zero. Finally

$$\mathcal P = \{0\} \cup \{ \pm z^n \mid n \ge 0\}$$

Comment: It works for power series with integer coefficients too (that converge on the unit disk)